# Snowflake terraform for queries

Tags: terraform, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, okta

I wanted to execute few queries for the Snowflake with terraform like.
use role admin;
alter account set saml_identity_provider = '{
"certificate": "test",
"ssoUrl": "https://abccorp.okta.com/app/<okta_snowflake_app_id>/sso/saml",
"type" : "OKTA"
}';

I want to execute queries like this.Is there any terraform templates that is available,

Comment: There are no templates for this requirement but you may check this for a start:https://github.com/ShopRunner/terraform-provider-snowflake

Answer (score 1):

There is a terraform provider plugin for managing Snowflake accounts. Coverage is focused on the parts of Snowflake that are related to access control. Example use cases include:

- Set up storage in your cloud provider and add it to Snowflake as an external stage
- Add storage and connect it to Snowpipe
- Create a service user and push the key into the secrets manager of your choice, or rotate keys

[Terraforming Snowflake](https://quickstarts.snowflake.com/guide/terraforming_snowflake/index.html)